# how can label my data is old and new in a minus sql

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to include an additional column that will tell whether data results for the  row is "old" or "new" in this minus query.

```
(select * from x1 minus select * from x2) -old
union all
(select * from x2 minus select * from x1) - new
```

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is this:

```
(select x1.*, 'old' as which from x1 minus select x2.*, 'old' as which from x2)
union all
(select x2.*, 'new' as which from x2 minus select x1.*, 'new' as which from x1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
SQL> with
  2    t1 as (select job from emp where deptno = 10
  3           minus
  4           select job from emp where deptno = 20
  5          ),
  6    t2 as (select job from emp where deptno = 20
  7           minus
  8           select job from emp where deptno = 30
  9          )
 10  select 'old' what, t1.* from t1
 11  union all
 12  select 'new' what, t2.* from t2;

WHA JOB
--- ---------
old PRESIDENT
new ANALYST

SQL>
```